# Debug in VS as non-admin

Tags: .net, debugging, code-access-security, non-admin

I'm doing some WinForms development, running XP and VS 2005 (ancient, I know).  I'd like to make sure my application can run without admin rights, but I'm too lazy to try to run VS as a non-admin, and I don't want to log in and out to test my app.

Is there a way I can just debug as a non-admin?

Is there a set of code access security attributes I can add to my code that will force me to run in the same permission set as a non admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run VS as another user from your current logged in desktop session. See [How to enable and use the "Run As" command when running programs in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676). This means you won't have to log-in and out.

I would suggest that you just run your target application as another user, via RunAs, then attach the VS Debugger to the process (if needed), via the Debug > Attach To Process... menu item in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Phil's answer, you can automate the process by setting the startup project to:

Start the external program: `c:\windows\system32\runas.exe`

with the Command line arguments: `/noprofile /user:{MachineName}\{UserName} {ApplicationName}.exe`

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an automatic way to attach the process to the VS debugger (because of the security warning), but by conditionally calling

```
#if (DEBUG) 
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

you will be prompted to attach to a debugger with two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this with a more fundamental change:

If you enable your computer to allow concurrent Remote Desktop sessions ([Vista](http://www.missingremote.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1220&Itemid=224), [XP](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/13/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/), use Google for others), then initiate a Remote Desktop session to 127.0.0.2, you can run as a completely different user on your local system, enabling you to do whatever you would like without having to switch between users.

For me, I normally run as a non-administrative user, but initiate a Remote Desktop session as an Administrator whenever I need to run an administrative task.  But, you can do the opposite just as easily.